# PowerBI - Additional Files

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

[image]

I have created a PowerBI. The source of the data is a SQL database. The amount of data I am working with is over 4M rows but unfortunately, PowerBI is not able to load the data. When I look at the TaskManager (see image), I see multiple subprocesses that seem to be running in the background. The file does not give me an error, but it just runs the entire night and still does not load the 4-5M rows.

Is this something y'all have seen before? None of my colleagues have seen this. Would love any inputs.

Thank you,
Kruthika

Comment: Nope.  Not a Power BI problem.  Check your SQL Server for locking,

Comment: 4 M rows is not even big data. If you're not familiar with Power BI you could easily switch to Excel instead.

Comment: `Microsoft Mashup Evaluation Container` process is the Power Query, which loads and transforms your data. `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess` is the Chromium Embedded Framework, i.e. the web browser, which renders the report. So all this is normal. It looks like your data source is failing to provide the data, because all these processes looks idle and doesn't consume much memory.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I've read that 4M is not a lot. I am really unable to figure out why it is unable to handle the query. 
It could also be that maybe it is timing out? I'm not sure because it is not giving me an error. Any idea how long it could typically take to process 4M rows?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov 
Thank you for confirming that those processes have a purpose. Is it not odd that there are so many of them? 
I also need to check the SQL front to make sure it is working fine.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft SQL locking, I will check for that as well.